# How to Slow down the browser

Tags: javascript, performance, browser

I am trying to test my application performance in different browsers (specially ie6).

Also I have ie8, ff and Chrome installed. I am using tool like ietester to see how my app looks in ie6.

I am trying to find a way, as how my application will behave if the browser is relatively slow (keeping the bandwidth/network speed same.). Is there a tool or a way to just slow down my browser (so that the page loads slowly and hance the js libraries load slowly) ?

Thanks for your help!!