# Network throttling with chrome and selenium

Tags: performance, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, bandwidth-throttling

Google Chrome 38 introduced the new ["Device Mode & Mobile Emulation"](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode) functionality in devtools. In addition to choosing a device for emulation, it is also possible to [emulate different network conditions](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode#network-conditions):

> Optimizing your site's performance under varying network conditions is
>   a key aspect of developing for a mobile audience.
>
> Device mode's network conditioning allows you to test your site on a
>   variety of network connections, including Edge, 3G, and even offline.
>   Select a connection from the preset dropdown to apply network
>   throttling and latency manipulation.

For example, we can set it to be like in good old days - GPRS 50 Kbps:

[image]

Now we have a good use case for it - we have an internal application for network speed testing. And this new emulation functionality is very helpful for manual testing. But, we'd like to automate it.

Question is:

Is it possible to start chrome via selenium with specified network conditions? Is it something that can be controlled through chrome preferences or command-line arguments?

---

There are certainly multiple options to [simulate slow internet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536249/simulating-slow-internet-connection), but the question is specifically about chrome+selenium.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The API to control network emulation [were added](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=984) to ChromeDriver. And should be available for quite a while now. According to [comment](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=984#c16) in the linked issue you should use version at least 2.26 because of some bugfix.

According to Selenium [changelog](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/releases) bindings are available for these languages:

- JavaScript as of version 3.4.0 ([commit](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/commit/d7bdd7cc42faafb1eba031c26b7c369cdea026d5))
- Python as of version 3.5.0 ([commit](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/commit/7ba13118ace82f2f58073dc35ab05d3ca47eb0a0))
- Ruby as of version 3.11.0 ([commit](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/1103cb7e9e35e8bd22a5aea9b5455445baa6fb85#diff-b1ade8967288d0002579a914345a9f56R37))
- C# as of version 4 ([commit](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/e2bc8ea0e90c3fb4b18c1efa284251edee9f7ed9))

If you need these binding in other languages you should probably open issue/contribute implementation similar to one of the above.

Example usage from Python is below:

```
driver.set_network_conditions(
    offline=False,
    latency=5,  # additional latency (ms)
    download_throughput=500 * 1024,  # maximal throughput
    upload_throughput=500 * 1024)  # maximal throughput
```

Comment: Is download_throughput & upload_throughput in bytes per second? So the examples roughly 5MB/s?

Comment: @Cynic In Chrome Dev Tools it says `kb/s`. My assumption is that it is the same when using API. But I haven't tested myself. Please edit the answer if/when you figure it out.

Comment: It's weird. If I use dev tools to toggle it on and put in like 5 * 1024 and test at  http://speedtest.xfinity.com (Easy to find start button) I get 5 mbps. But if I do the same in a Selenium script, 5 * 1024 it basically doesn't register. To get around 5 mbps I need to do something around 5 * 30000 to get something that tops out around 5 mbps (on a 300 mbps+ if I don't throttle in the script so not internet). Maybe a bug though as that doesn't correspond well to any conversion I can think of.

Comment: Here's a link to the JS code: 

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/e4696a29290beb8db539285681b6c67534940842/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js#L752

Comment: According to the comments in the ChromeDriver code [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/test/chromedriver/chrome/network_conditions.cc#74), it appears then when you are overriding the network conditions you are providing the throughput speeds in bps, even though the presets are listed in kbps.

Comment: Note that it does not yet affect websocket connections, see https://crbug.com/423246

Comment: Thanks @YaroslavAdmin it really helped!!

Comment: From what I am seeing it appears the input to download_throughput is measured in Bytes per second. Not bits. I may be crazy, but that's how the numbers seem to be working out. So if you want 500 kbps: `download_throughput=500 / 8 * 1024,` Let me know if anyone else is seeing the same. Kind of hard to measure definitively.

Comment: That's super useful, thanks a lot @YaroslavAdmin! Testing scripts -- and dealing with the edge cases that throttling reveals -- definitely helps make those scripts more robust. Cheers!

Answer (score 16):

No, it is not possible to control [Network Connectivity Emulation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode#network-conditions) through Chrome preferences or command-line arguments. Network Connectivity Emulation is part of the build-in Chrome debugger. One way way in solving this is to control the debugger. This can be done via an extension or by directly controlling the debugger, see [explanation](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=373169#c11). However, this will not work with WebDriver. The reason for this is that there can only be one "debug" session and WebDriver is already using it, see [explanation](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/help/devtools-window-keeps-closing). Since there is no public interface, there is also no way to control it via WebDriver.

For [Device Mode & Mobile Emulation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode) which is also part of the build-in  debugger, there is a public interface ([details](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/mobile-emulation)), and thus can be controlled. This can be done through WebDriver Capabilities. Two options  1) Specify a device name 2) Enter your own parameters (limited).

Comment: You may want to remove this answer, as this is now possible via Selenium.

Answer (score 8):

You can use this method to run your test case in  specified network conditions

```
protected void networkThrotting() throws IOException {
  Map map = new HashMap();
  map.put("offline", false);
  map.put("latency", 5);
  map.put("download_throughput", 500);
  map.put("upload_throughput", 1024);


  CommandExecutor executor = ((ChromeDriver)driver).getCommandExecutor();
  Response response = executor.execute(
        new Command(((ChromeDriver)driver).getSessionId(),    "setNetworkConditions", ImmutableMap.of("network_conditions", ImmutableMap.copyOf(map)))
  );
}
```

Comment: Was anyone able to use this? When I try to use this I am getting `org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: setNetworkConditions` exception. I have tried changing it to `setNetworkConnection`, but that does not have any impact in the network speed!

Answer (score 5):

While this is a very welcome and useful bit of functionality, for serious testing I think the conventional methods of network simulation are still the way to go.

I am aware of 2 solutions in addition to those already linked - the [Charles web proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) (very useful tool - commercial) and implementing your own recipe using Linux Traffic Control (e.g. see chapter 6 of [LAMPe2e](https://www.smashwords.com/books/view/509497)).

By interfering with the network connections rather than the browser, you then get a proper measure of the impact independently of the browser in use.

Why do you just want to use the Chrome functionality?

Answer (score 5):

Indeed C# Selenium latest (3.11) has NetworkConditions added. Now you can use it like this:

```
     var driver = new ChromeDriver(pathToDriver);
     driver.NetworkConditions = new ChromeNetworkConditions()
     {  DownloadThroughput = 5000, UploadThroughput = 5000, Latency = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5) };
```

The problem is it's not yet usable because of the bug

> https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5693

So .Net guys will have to wait until 3.12 Selenium Release.

Answer (score 4):

Let's consider two different approaches,

one where we can throttle the entire network and one where we can specify which network requests to throttle specifically.

Approach 1: throttle the entire network

```
const { Builder } = require("selenium-webdriver")

async function throttleNetwork() {
  let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();

  await driver.setNetworkConditions({
    offline: false,
    latency: 5000, // Additional latency (ms).
    download_throughput: 50 * 1024, // Maximal aggregated download throughput.
    upload_throughput: 50 * 1024, // Maximal aggregated upload throughput.
  });

  driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
}
```

thanks to [Yaroslav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1377864/yaroslav-admin) for pointing out the commit.

This has a downside where we can't specify a specific network request to throttle and the rest to go unthrottled.

Let's fix this downside in our next approach.

Approach 2: throttle a specific network request

Here we'd be using an npm package from [requestly](https://requestly.io/) called [Requestly for Selenium](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@requestly/selenium).

We need to create a rule first in their [client application](https://app.requestly.io/) and get the link by creating a shared list.

For example, let's throttle network request to google.com

```
require("chromedriver");
const { Builder } = require("selenium-webdriver");
const chrome = require("selenium-webdriver/chrome");
const {
  getRequestlyExtension,
  importRequestlySharedList,
} = require("@requestly/selenium");

const sharedListUrl = "YOUR_SHARED_LIST_LINK_HERE" // For example, use "https://app.requestly.io/rules/#sharedList/1631611216670-delay"

async function throttleGoogle() {
  const options = new chrome.Options().addExtensions(
    getRequestlyExtension("chrome") // This installs requestly chrome extension in your testing instance
  );

  const driver = new Builder()
    .forBrowser("chrome")
    .setChromeOptions(options)
    .build();

  await importRequestlySharedList(driver, sharedListUrl); // Here we import the shared list we created some time back
  driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
}
```

This was a high-level overview of how we can overcome the downsides of the selenium-only approach. I've written a blog on the same where I go into depth on how to create a rule, shared list, and so on. You can read it [here](https://requestly.io/blog/2021/09/20/automate-testing-via-selenium/).

Answer (score 3):

**The below issue has now been fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/cd12f66955f456ba56480087c53a747c745b0886)**

For anyone like me in the C# world wondering why the upload/download throughput does not work as expected, it seems the tooltips for these properties are mislabelled. The tooltip states the data rate is measured in kb/s but in my own experience it is actually bytes per second so if you want to use a more familiar measurement like Mbps you will have to multiply by 125,000:

```
int latencyInMilliseconds = 20;
long downloadLimitMbps = 20;
long uploadLimitMbps = 5;
_driver.NetworkConditions = new ChromeNetworkConditions()
{
    Latency = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, latencyInMilliseconds),
    DownloadThroughput = downloadLimitMbps * 125000, // Mbps to bytes per second
    UploadThroughput = uploadLimitMbps * 125000, // Mbps to bytes per second
    IsOffline = false,
};
```

Using these settings and looking at network traffic while my tests are running I can see they result in exactly 20Mbps down and 5Mbps up.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's coming soon to Selenium (C#). The commit was on 01/28/2018:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/ef156067a583fe84b66ec338d969aeff6504595d/dotnet/src/webdriver/Chrome/ChromeNetworkConditions.cs

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I recently had to solve for this problem and this page came up at the top of my Google search. Here are the main bits from how I did it in C#. Hope this helps someone in the future.

```cs
var networkConditions = new ChromeNetworkConditions();
networkConditions.Latency = new TimeSpan(150);
networkConditions.IsOffline = false;
networkConditions.DownloadThroughput = 120 * 1024;
networkConditions.UploadThroughput = 150 * 1024;
Driver.NetworkConditions = networkConditions;
```

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by the answer from [TridentTrue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3604287/tridenttrue), here is an updated version for Selenium 4.0.0 in C#. If anyone knows how to use it for alpha7 and upwards without beeing version specific feel free to update this. :)

```
public void LimitNetwork(int latencyInMilliseconds, long downloadLimitMbps, long uploadLimitMbps)
{
    IDevTools devTools = driver as IDevTools;
    session = devTools.CreateDevToolsSession();
    session.Network.Enable(new EnableCommandSettings());

    EmulateNetworkConditionsCommandSettings command = new EmulateNetworkConditionsCommandSettings();

    command.Latency = latencyInMilliseconds;
    command.DownloadThroughput = downloadLimitMbps * 125000; // Mbps to bytes per second
    command.UploadThroughput = uploadLimitMbps * 125000; // Mbps to bytes per second
    command.Offline = false;

    session.Network.EmulateNetworkConditions(command);
}
```

Update: After I had implemented this for my own, I found a really good article to get an [overview in Selenium 4.0](https://www.automatetheplanet.com/selenium-webdriver-4-overview/), also in Emulating network conditions.

Update 2: My issue was that I forgot to add the Network.Enable command, so don't forget to call it before you do the other stuff.
I have updated the code. :)