# Simulate network loss with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium and ChromeDriver to write a test to simulate network connection loss.

```
this.chromeDriver.setNetworkConnection(NetworkConnection.ConnectionType.AIRPLANE_MODE);
//wait and do actions
this.chromeDriver.setNetworkConnection(NetworkConnection.ConnectionType.WIFI);
//asserts
```

My tests run within a container, and currently I am casting an injected instance of a WebDriver that I know is Chrome as `this.chromeDriver = (ChromeDriver)this.webDriver;`
Looking online I do not see a way to turn off network connectivity through the WebDriver instance, and I would like to avoid turning off/on on host level just for the test. Is there a better way of achieving network simulation using Selenium in 3.6?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is direct interface management using Java.
For example:

```
Runtime.getRuntime ().exec ("ipconfig/release");
```

Naturally, you need to take into account specific points as an operating system.

Answer (score 0):

edit: I noticed just now you asked for an answer in 3.6 and this is only for 4.0+ so apologies

You can use the chromium CommandExecutor in your own function like so:

```
public static void driverGoOffline(ChromeDriver driver) throws RuntimeException {
    Map map = new HashMap();
    map.put("offline", true);
    CommandExecutor executor = ((ChromeDriver)driver).getCommandExecutor();
    try
    {
        Response response = executor.execute(
            new Command(((ChromeDriver)driver).getSessionId(), "setNetworkConditions", ImmutableMap.of("network_conditions", ImmutableMap.copyOf(map)))
        );
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

More info https://stackoverflow.com/a/56526094/17892492

It is best to do it within the automated browser rather than throttling your machine's actual internet connection for many reasons