# Network connection throttling with Selenium - Java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have been trying to implement network throttling with Selenium-WebDriver based on the snippet available here in this post. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56526094/2122388

Re-posting the code from above link:

```
protected void networkThrotting() throws IOException {
  Map map = new HashMap();
  map.put("offline", false);
  map.put("latency", 5);
  map.put("download_throughput", 500);
  map.put("upload_throughput", 1024);

  CommandExecutor executor = ((ChromeDriver)driver).getCommandExecutor();
  Response response = executor.execute(
        new Command(((ChromeDriver)driver).getSessionId(), "setNetworkConditions", ImmutableMap.of("network_conditions", ImmutableMap.copyOf(map)))
  );
}
```

It throws as exception like `org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: setNetworkConditions`. With my debugging, found like there is no definition for `setNetworkConditions` in `AbstractHttpCommandCodec` but found `setNetworkConnection`. SO tried changing this as below:

```
protected void networkThrotting() throws IOException {
      Map map = new HashMap();
      map.put("offline", false);
      map.put("latency", 5);
      map.put("download_throughput", 500);
      map.put("upload_throughput", 1024);
    
      CommandExecutor executor = ((ChromeDriver)driver).getCommandExecutor();
      Response response = executor.execute(
            new Command(((ChromeDriver)driver).getSessionId(), "setNetworkConnection", ImmutableMap.of("network_connection", ImmutableMap.copyOf(map)))
      );
    }
```

It does not throw any exception and let the test pass, but there is no change in the network speed as intended. I am using Selenium 3.x and Chrome 100.x.

So any input here is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is here because of same issue, then here is the solutions (alternate) I figured out at the end:

1. Upgrade to Selenium-4.x and use DevTools can make things much easier and straightforward
2. Use BrowserMob-Proxy and play around

I chose Option-2 for implementing the network throttling, since I had some limitations in upgrading my Selenium version to 4.x *(but upgrading the Selenium version is much simple and easy solution).*

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example to help others about how to use Selenium-4.x version with DevTools.

```
try (DevTools devTools = ((ChromeDriver) driver).getDevTools()) {
        devTools.createSession();

        devTools.send(Network.enable(Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(), Optional.empty()));

        // network offline
        devTools.send(Network.emulateNetworkConditions(true, 0, 0, 0, Optional.of(ConnectionType.WIFI)));

        // Your offline code puts here.

}
// Your online code puts here, if any.
```

**Note**: Your Chrome Driver version should match the Selenium-Devtools version, for example

```
'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-vNN:SELENIUM_VERSION'
```

*vNN* is your chrome version like *selenium-devtools*-***v111:4.8.3*** with Selenium *4.8.3* version.