# Simulating poor browser JavaScript performance using Web Workers

Tags: javascript, performance, web-worker

I am trying to simulate slow browser performance by using web workers. I have seen a similar [question about throttling JavaScript performance here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521683/is-there-a-way-to-throttle-javascript-performance-to-simulate-a-slow-client), but it was asked many years ago, and without any reference to [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

I can create a web worker on the fly, and have it run an infinite loop. Therefore, I can take up CPU without blocking JavaScript in the actual tab.

Here is how I am doing this:

```
var workerCount = 0;

function addWorker() {
    var blob = new Blob(
        ['while (true) {}'],
        {type: "text/javascript"}
    );
    var worker = new Worker(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
    return 'Worker Count: ' + ++workerCount;
}
```

Then, I can call it from the console in that particular tab:

```
> addWorker();
< "Worker Count: 1"
```

I can see this action take up the CPU for that tab as I add workers. The fan on my computer even gets going pretty crazy. The following shows the CPU usage for 3 workers added to the page:

[image: CPU usage is high for 3 web workers at once]

As stated before, the helpful thing about using the web workers is that I can still execute JavaScript in that tab without it being blocked. I can run the following **in the same tab** even with the 3 workers running and it executes immediately:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

---

**What I want to achieve:**

I am trying to simulate an environment where maybe animations become more "choppy", `.show()`, `.hide()` functions take a moment to activate, etc.

While I can see the CPU usage being taken up, will this actually help simulate an environment of poor JavaScript performance in that tab? Should I maybe take up the CPU and **more memory** instead?

Comment: What is the base case for _"poor Javascript performance"_? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you thread javascript? if not I would say no, however I do not really know.

Comment: LOL, I just looked it up to see and found this http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/introducing-html-5-web-workers-bringing-multi-threading-to-javascript.html#fbid=lHB31T8KlwH

Comment: i don't think workers would be a good way to slow down the main thread, they are designed to be apart...

Comment: @dandavis, possibly, that's what I'm hoping to find out. From what I see in the activity monitor, web workers effect the CPU usage for the tab, which is where the normal page JavaScript will be executing so I would assume this would have an overall performance impact.

Comment: _"I am trying to simulate an environment where maybe animations become more "choppy""_ Not following, here. Can you create a stacksnippets to demonstrate where animatations become "choppy"? Not certain what requirement is?

Comment: set a short interval running a small while loop to cause main thread chop.

Comment: Why not just go with a VM as indicated in the linked post? Browser makers try very hard to make animation *not* choppy, and you're trying to undermine that. Also, I believe some browsers use the GPU for animation, so you might be out of luck.

Comment: that reminds me, you can change some chrome flags to kill optimizations and accelerations, and the devtools has a network throttle.

Comment: Just as others, I wanna advise that you use virtual machine. Method with web workers is unreliable - you never know what is actually going on, how is CPU load getting deferred etc...