# CPU throttling in chrome via python selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to throttle CPU in chrome's devtools via python selenium? And if so, how?

It would appear the driver has a method `execute_cdp_cmd` which stands for "Execute Chrome Devtools Protocol command" but I do not know what command I would give it.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521683/is-there-a-way-to-throttle-javascript-performance-to-simulate-a-slow-client) suggests it is possible in devtools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear to be possible in chromedriver 75.

```py
## rate 1 is no throttle, 2 is 2x slower, etc. 
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Emulation.setCPUThrottlingRate", {'rate': 10})
```

NOTE:

2.38 didn't seem to support `execute_cdp_cmd()` while 2.48 *did*.  Chromedriver also appears to have changed their versioning scheme to keep in sync with browser releases.

I did some quick checking and was able to push the throttle rate to upwards of 200x but it started having serious issues.  My guess it going beyond 100x is ill-advised.

Answer (score 0):

```
## rate 1 is no throttle, 2 is 2x slower, etc. 
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Emulation.setCPUThrottlingRate", {'rate': 10})
```

This still works today!