# Throttle CPU in chromedriver with selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So I'm trying to add the `CPUThrottlingRate` in my `selenium` `chromedriver` setup below.

```rb
require 'webdrivers/chromedriver'

module ChromeBrowser
  class << self

    def headless(throttling)
      @browser ||= headless_chrome_browser(throttling || 'regular')
    end

    private

    def headless_chrome_browser(throttling)
      options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new

      # -> https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#profiler-timing
      options.add_argument '--ignore-certificate-errors'
      # options.add_argument "--user-agent=#{random_user_agent}" # set Random User Agent
      options.add_argument '--allow-insecure-localhost'
      options.add_argument '--window-size=1400x1400'
      options.add_argument '--disable-gpu'
      options.add_argument '--disable-dev-shm-usage'
      options.add_argument '--noerrdialogs' # Suppresses all error dialogs when present
      options.add_argument '--profiler-timing=0' # whether chrome will contain timing information
      options.add_argument '--disable-infobars' # prevent infobars from appearing
      options.add_argument '--headless' if Rails.env.production? # headless on chrome
      # options.add_argument '--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false' # disable images
      options.add_argument '--no-referrers' # don't send HTTP-Referer headers
      options.add_argument '--disable-breakpad' # disables the crash reporting
      options.add_argument '--disable-demo-model' # disables the chrome OS demo
      options.add_argument '--disable-translate' # disable google translate
      options.add_argument '--dns-prefetch-disable' # disable DNS prefetching
      options.add_argument '--no-pings' # no hyperlink auditing pings

      browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options

      case throttling
      when 'slow'
        browser.network_conditions = {
          offline: false,
          latency: 50,
          download_throughput: 51200,
          upload_throughput: 51200
        }
      when 'regular'
        browser.network_conditions = {
          offline: false,
          latency: 30,
          download_throughput: 51200,
          upload_throughput: 512000
        }
      when 'fast'
        browser.network_conditions = {
          offline: false,
          latency: 20,
          download_throughput: 1024000,
          upload_throughput: 1024000
        }
      end

      return browser
    end
  end
end
```

I'm looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57008946/cpu-throttling-in-chrome-via-python-selenium) solution here but in ruby.

```
## rate 1 is no throttle, 2 is 2x slower, etc. 
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Emulation.setCPUThrottlingRate", {'rate': 10})
```

- `developertools` is installed
- `running on chromedriver v92`

> I'm trying to throttle both network speed and CPU to simulate ~kinda~ real-life requests.

Can't seem to figure it out, what am I missing? Useful links:

- https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/support_packages/chrome_devtools/
- [CPU throttling in chrome via python selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57008946/cpu-throttling-in-chrome-via-python-selenium)
- https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Ruby-Bindings

---

I have tried:

```rb
...
browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options
devToolsSession = browser.devtools
devToolsSession.send_cmd('Emulation.setCPUThrottlingRate', {rate: 10})
```

Which produces

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
from /Users/minijohn/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.0.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/devtools.rb:55:in `send_cmd'
```

and with one param

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: -32602: Invalid parameters: Failed to deserialize params.rate - BINDINGS: mandatory field missing at position 7
from /Users/minijohn/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.0.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/devtools.rb:69:in `send_cmd'
```

Also tried this

```rb
browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options
browser.send_cmd('Emulation.setCPUThrottlingRate', {rate: 10})
```

which produces

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `send_cmd' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Driver:0x2738339e1fe77884 browser=:chrome>
from (pry):14:in `headless_chrome_browser'
```

Comment: Wiki is outdated, I haven't moved updated content to docs. You should be able to figure out what you need from this: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/support_packages/chrome_devtools/

Comment: That's exactly the same link as I have above :p Are you referring to the `execute_cdp` or `send_cmd` calls? I couldn't get this to work. Any insight?

Comment: @titusfortner I updated the question with the bits from the selenium docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal for Selenium is to define the common commands that the browser vendors will support in the WebDriver BiDi specification, and support them  via a straightforward API, which will be accessible via `Driver#devtools` method.

In the meantime, any Chrome DevTools command can be executed via `Driver#execute_cdp`.

In this case it will look like:

```
SL-1495:code titusfortner$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'selenium-webdriver'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
=> #<Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Driver:0x..fc42365c4d30079b0 browser=:chrome>
irb(main):003:0> driver.execute_cdp('Emulation.setCPUThrottlingRate', rate: 10)
=> {}
irb(main):004:0>
```

The key here is that in Ruby we're using keywords for this instead of a Hash, and in Ruby 3, those are now handled differently.